# function exp(exponential) cannot be used in a constant expression - gcc extension

Tags: c++, g++, c++14, constexpr, cmath

I want to compute a lookup table at compile time for a mathematical function in a given range and then retrieve values from the table at run time. My code is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>


template<int size>
class LookupTable {
public:
constexpr LookupTable(double xMin, double xMax) : array(), xMin(xMin), xMax(xMax), dx((xMax - xMin) / (size - 1)) {
    for(auto i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        array[i] = exp(xMin + i * dx);
}

constexpr double operator()(double x) const {
    return array[std::min(std::max(static_cast<int>((x - xMin) / dx), 0), size-1)];
}

private:
double array[size];
double xMin;
double xMax;
double dx;
};



int main() {
    const double x = 0.5;
    constexpr LookupTable<10000> table(0.0, 1.0);
    std::cout << "f(x) = " << table(x) << std::endl;  // evaluated at compile time ?
    std::cout << "f(x) = " << LookupTable<10000>(0.0, 1.0)(x) << std::endl;  // evaluated at run time ?
    return 0;
}
```

The code compiles and runs on gcc 5.1 and above but not on Clang 3.8.
Clang's error messages are: constexpr variable 'table' must be initialized by a constant expression and non-constexpr function 'exp' cannot be used in a constant expression.

When I remove the constexpr in:

```
constexpr LookupTable<10000> table(0.0, 1.0);
```

then the code compiles and runs on Clang as well.

My questions are:

- What is the meaning of the error message "function 'exp' cannot be used in a constant expression" ? And is there a workaround?
- Does that mean that when I declare LookupTable<10000> table(0.0, 1.0); without the constexpr, then the table precomputations happen at run-time?
  I am using an online compiling tool so I do not have an option to benchmark the code right now.
- I would like to generalize the code and templatize the mathematical function. It works fine with functors but is it possible to use lambdas?

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This appears to be a non-conforming extension of gcc since `exp()` is declared without `constexpr` in `<cmath>`:

> **17.6.5.6 constexpr functions and constructors [constexpr.functions]**
>
> 1 This standard explicitly requires that
>   certain standard library functions are constexpr (7.1.5). **An
>   implementation shall not declare any standard library function
>   signature as constexpr except for those where it is explicitly
>   required.** Within any header that provides any non-defining
>   declarations of constexpr functions or constructors an implementation
>   shall provide corresponding definitions.

Without the `constexpr` in front of your `LookupTable`, it will indeed be initalized at runtime. A work-around is to make it a `static` variable, so that you can initialize it at start-up time.

If you want `constexpr` math functions, you need to write your own, or alternatively, write a Standard proposal that the current `<cmath>` library is modified to be `constexpr`.

Answer (score 0):

Note that adding [more constexpr for cmath and complex](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2023/p1383r2.pdf) has been proposed for C++23. This includes `std::exp` and many others. It has been accepted for integration to C++26. It is already partially supported by gcc since 4.6 but no other compilers, at least officially, see [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support)).